# When can a double limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{k,m}(x)$ be combined into $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{k,k}(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, uniform-convergence

Let $f_{k,m}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}, \forall k, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{k,m} = f_{k,-}$ uniformly in $m$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{k,m} = f_{-,m}$ at least pointwise. Can I then combine the double limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{k,m}$ to $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{k,m} = \lim_{k\to\infty}f_{k,k}$? I already tried to search my analysis notes and books, but as this sort of limit combining is quite rare at least in standard curriculum (I cannot reside any that important theorem that combines limits), so I could not find anything useful. I am aware that under these assumptions conditions one can change the order of the limits of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{k,m}$ to $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{k,m}$.

**Edit:** A guiding motivation to my question relates to convergence discussed in a problem such as this: [Dense subspace of the space of functions vanishing at infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497615/dense-subspace-of-the-space-of-functions-vanishing-at-infinity), where one acceptable approach is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1497686/820472). If I understood that answer correctly, we are showing that we can approximate a continuous function $\tilde{f}_k$ with a compact support in the infinity norm with a sequence of smooth compactly supported functions $g_{k,m}$. We are taking it as granted that we can approximate a continuous function $f$ vanishing at infinity with such $\tilde{f}_k$s, so in the end we are approximating $f$ with a sequence that itself is approximated with some other functions. Therefore once wrote out, the entire expression is something like

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}||f - \tilde{f}_k||_\infty = \lim_{k\to \infty}||f - \lim_{m\to\infty}g_{k,m}||_\infty$$

Comment: Better not use $n$ both as an index of the sequence *and* as the dimension of the space :)

Comment: @MartinR Ah, good catch! It is now fixed. Although I would be intrigued to know what you could say for example about such a function whose index is tied to the dimension of the ambient space!

Comment: Does the “uniform” refer to $x$? Then this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/631292/42969 is a counterexample, consider the constant functions $f_{k, m}(x) = 1$ if $k \le m$ and $f_{k, m}(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: I guess (for tied dimensions) you could identify functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ to the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ constant relative to all the components of index $\geq n+1$ as a starting point? Not that I have any clue for what you'd do after that hmm

Comment: @MartinR Hmm, that is an interesting example! But to your question, by "uniform" I originally thought that I wanted something along the lines of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Interchanging_limits_of_sequences_of_functions

I will write more to an edit to this post.

Comment: In *”$\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{k,m}(x) = f_{k,-}(x)$ uniformly”* the “uniformly” can refer to $x$, or to $k$, or to both. You should clarify what exactly your assumptions are.

Comment: @MartinR I see. I have edited my post. The uniform convergence referred to the index $m$ in $\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{f,m}(x)=f_{x,-}(x)$.

Comment: @EpsilonAway: What does "uniformly in $m$” mean in this context? Are you sure that you don't mean “uniformly in $k$”? It might be helpful to write down all your assumptions explicitly in terms of $\epsilon$, $m, k, x$ etc.

Comment: @MartinR Agreed. I will get back to clarifying this question maybe later this week. I had a vague idea what I wanted based on an example I was working with, but as this discussion shows, I had not properly verbalized the context.